# How to add an action in a nav-link in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've a project where i need to use the MVC2 architecture. So far so good, but I'm stuck with the navigation bar.

Basically, I'm making a webpage where I have a navigation bar with different options available. When I click in one of the options, I want an "action" to be made, which would be sent to an Action Builder Class which would generate a view with the specific page.

For instance, this is my ActionBuilder class, which is in my Controler folder

```
<?php
require_once('./controleur/DefaultAction.class.php');
require_once('./controleur/MenuAction.class.php');
require_once('./controleur/LogginAction.class.php');
require_once('./controleur/ContactAction.class.php');

class ActionBuilder{
public static function getAction($nomAction){
    switch ($nomAction)
    {
            case "Menu" :
            return new MenuAction();
            break; 
                case "Tarification" :
                return new TarificationAction();
                break; 
                    case "Contact" :
                    return new ContactAction();
                    break; 
        default :
            return new DefaultAction();
    }
}
}
?>
```

Here is my css:

```
  <form method="post" action="">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarColor01" style="">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="APropos">À propos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="Tarification">Tarif</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="MenuOffert.php">Menus offert</a> 
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"  id="Contact">Nous contacter</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="Loggin.PHP">Se connecter</a>
                          </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

After we clicked, for example Contacter in the navigation bar, what I need is to send an action to the controler which would call this ContactAction class:

```
  <?php
 require_once('./controleur/Action.interface.php');
class ContactAction implements Action {
public function execute(){
    return "Contact";
  }
 }
```

which eventually would show the page with the info that I need.
How can I do this?

Also, do I have to set a form in the navigation bar as I did? I'm really not sure for that part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add your **url** where you want to display the page to your navigation.

> example: À propos

edit the `href="#"` to `href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/add/your/link')"`

Comment: I know that we can do it that way. But what I'm looking for is a little  more something like this:  
      <input name="action" value="Rechercher" type="hidden" />
Do I have to chance all of the link-navgs for something like this?

Comment: nope, you can't because inputs can be only submitted through forms and links are use to redirect links to another page.

Comment: but if you want too. instead of putting a link to your navigation just add you link to your form and put an hidden input to it.

Comment: I've tried it without success, could you show me how to do it?

Comment: <form action="your link to submit the form" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="" value=""> <input type="submit" value="submit"> </form